# How to get value from select using jquery

Tags: jquery

Prefer this example so you have better idea for give answer

```
<select id="cmbfotos" onchange="aplicarFoto()">
    <option value="gokussj3.jpg">Value 1</option>
    <option value="gokussj4.jpg">Value 2</option>
    <option value="gohanssj2.jpg">Value 3</option>
    <option value="gotenks.jpg">Value 4</option>
    <option value="krilin.jpg">Value 5</option>
</select>
```

In above ex. when i select two value like Value1 and value2 both value i require 
so how to i get it.

i not require value like "gokussj3.jpg" but Value 1

If some idea share me .....

Comment: What do you mean "two value", it's not a multiple, so you can only select one value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this solution for your requirement

// Use for multiple select in select

```
 $('#cmbfotos  option').each(function() 
    {
        if($(this).val() == 'gokussj3.jpg') 
        {
            $(this).prop("selected", true);
        }
    });
```

// Get the value from a drop down select

```
$( "#cmbfotos option:selected").val();
```

// Get the value from a dropdown select even easier

```
$( "select.foo" ).val();
```

// Get the value from a checked check box

```
$( "input:checkbox:checked" ).val();
```

// Get the value from a set of radio buttons

```
$( "input:radio[name=bar]:checked" ).val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Access the options, filtering by `:selected`, then get the `.text()`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyh9C/)

```
$('#cmbfotos option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use jquery [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) for select onchange event, [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) to select all elements that are selected and [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get text from element. Try this:

```
$("#cmbfotos").change(function(){
    var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    alert(text);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/87uva/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#cmbfotos option:selected').text(); ////is for text and
    $('#cmbfotos option:selected').val() ///is for value;
```